# One USB flash drive to rule them all

Tags: macos, usb-flash-drive, operating-systems, grub

Yesterday I purchased a 32GB USB flash drive.  I have a myrid of systems in my home, and would like to have one flash drive with setup files for all the various systems throughout the house.  I kept the Fat 32 filesystem on the drive, as I figured that is probably the most universal.  I then made the partition bootable using fdisk.  I then copied the Windows 7 setup files to the drive.  I then installed grub 2 (1.98) onto the drive using backtrack 5.  I was then able to load the windows 7 setup / install from the flash drive on an older BIOS type motherboard.

Now I would like to know how to get this to work on my MacBook Pro 8,2 with still retaining support for legacy computers.  Is this possible, or is this just a pipe dream.

I plan on getting OS X on the drive, gparted, and OS X86 on the drive when all is said and done.  I've done various google searches but really haven't found a guide on how to setup a swiss army usb flash drive.

Comment: _One disk to rule them all; one disk to wipe them. One disk to hold the files, and in the darkness bind them…_

Comment: @BlacklightShining you're almost suggesting what is is doing  is bad but it's not.

Comment: Aww, c'mon! I'm only trying to be funny. :(

Comment: @BlacklightShining thats what I'm talking about :)

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do? dual/triple boot with that USB? You could create two partitions, one FAT32 and another MacOS Extenented Journaled. Restore the MacOS installation files in the Mac prtition using Disk Utility form within MacOS. I don't know about real Mac boot loaders, but in a PC (Hackintosh) if you install Chameleon on the Mac partition, it will detect the FAT32 partition and give you the option to either boot from the Mac partition on from the FAT32 partition. Beware! As far as I know Chameleon isn't compatible with a real Mac! You must find a way to allow booting from the FAT32 partition by propely configuring the Mac boot loader. Unfortunatelly, I'm not familiar with MacOS, so I cannot help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing refind or refit on your mac? Then you should (hopefully) be able to boot from a legacy USB. However, even with this installed there's no guarantee that it'll work. I have experienced that elder MACs (usually from a couple of years back and older) just don't want to boot legacy USBs. They have to be UEFI supported.